# eventProps.start is undefined fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Sorry about my English.

I put the `fullCalendar` 3.4.0 in my project, installed the latest version of `moment` under install-package from visual studio 2015.

I forgot something ? Here in Brazil, we utilize 24 hours format (00:00-23:59).

```
Error at start:
jQuery.Deferred exception: eventProps.start is undefined normalizeEventTimes@http://localhost:49523/Scripts/fullcalendar.js:13629:24
normalizeEventDates@http://localhost:49523/Scripts/fullcalendar.js:13609:3
assignDatesToEvent@http://localhost:49523/Scripts/fullcalendar.js:13600:3
buildEventFromInput@http://localhost:49523/Scripts/fullcalendar.js:13584:4
buildEventSource/source.events<@http://localhost:49523/Scripts/fullcalendar.js:13174:13
map@http://localhost:49523/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:3409
buildEventSource@http://localhost:49523/Scripts/fullcalendar.js:13173:21
EventManager/<@http://localhost:49523/Scripts/fullcalendar.js:12835:17
each@http://localhost:49523/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:2813
EventManager@http://localhost:49523/Scripts/fullcalendar.js:12832:2
constructor@http://localhost:49523/Scripts/fullcalendar.js:11300:3
$.fn.fullCalendar/<@http://localhost:49523/Scripts/fullcalendar.js:54:15
each@http://localhost:49523/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:2813
each@http://localhost:49523/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:1001
$.fn.fullCalendar@http://localhost:49523/Scripts/fullcalendar.js:35:2
@http://localhost:49523/:22:9
j@http://localhost:49523/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:29946
g/</k<@http://localhost:49523/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:30262

TypeError: eventProps.start is undefined
```

Comment: did you include all the relevant files into your actual web page, with the correct paths? I don't believe just installing the package does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the propblem. I unistalled the moment installed from install-package on visual studio 2015, and used the moment.min.js that come from fullcalendar.3.4.0 zip file.